# presentModalViewController inside UIViewController class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

```
View *view1 = [[View alloc] init];  
[self presentModalViewController:view1 animated:YES];
```

The code above works when connected to a `UIButton`. It does not work upon launch of an application by putting it in the `viewDidLoad:` method. I would like to run this upon launch.

Answer (score 5):

Look very closely at the method you're calling: `presentModalViewController:` presents a **controller**, not a view.

The correct pattern is something like this:

```
MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
[myViewController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6 you should use following method, because of deprections:

MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];